# How do I make sure I fetch data from api ONLY ONCE

Tags: java, android

I have an a few cards inflated, I fetch data from a website's api and insert it in the database and get back the first 3 rows with a seeAll option button to add fragmentB with the whole rows inflated from the databse. inside fragmentB I fetch the same from the same website just to make sure it was fetched and inserted in the database. is there a way to check before trying to fetch the api again?

better explanation:
This is the main layout, there are few other card below this one[image]

this is the fragment opened when I press See all

[image]
so once the application opens i fetch the api and inflate the main layout, when I add the new fragment I want to check if the link was fetched instead of just fetching it once its created

Comment: Some code would help... and please also clarify the question, it's difficult to understand what you're asking.

Comment: How would you check data without fetching it first?

Comment: @redFive I fetch it once I open the application, but sometimes there might be no connection while starting the app, so I want to make sure it was fetched when I press the see all and add the new fragment instead of just fetching it straight ahead onCreate of the new fragment

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any of your code... :

Save the data within an object you defined such as

```
private apiData recievedData = null;
```

Whenever you attempt to recieve data, you'll first check if the object is null.

```
if(recievedData == null)
{
     recievedData = getDataFromAPI();
}
return recievedData; //will return previously retrieved data if not null
```

Comment: well do I make it static so I can access it from the fragment? s=

Comment: @RedEagle depends on your project setup, but it sounds like your fragment should always be getting it from the activity. I'd create an interface adaptor.

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to first check the database and if the record's exists then do not fetch it from the server. Also, is there any reason of again fetching the data in FragmentB when you have already fetched it in FragmentA. Anyways, try to first check the database for the record and if the record doesn't exist then fetch it from API.

Comment: the thing is it needs to be updated, as everytime the player scores a goal it updates, so my thinking was creating a static boolean and check it from the fragment